# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 - 99% fragmentation on non-clustered, non-unique index

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4

I have a table with several indexes (defined below).  One of the indexes (IX_external_guid_3) has 99% fragmentation regardless of rebuilding/reorganizing the index.  Anyone have any idea as to what might cause this, or the best way to fix it?

We are using Entity Framework 4.0 to query this, the EF queries on the other indexed fields about 10x faster on average then the external_guid_3 field, however an ADO.Net query is roughly the same speed on both (though 2x slower than the EF Query to indexed fields).

*Table*

- id(PK, int, not null)
- guid(uniqueidentifier, null, rowguid)
- external_guid_1(uniqueidentifier, not null)
- external_guid_2(uniqueidentifier, null)
- state(varchar(32), null)
- value(varchar(max), null)
- infoset(XML(.), null) --> usually 2-4K
- created_time(datetime, null)
- updated_time(datetime, null)
- external_guid_3(uniqueidentifier, not
  null)
- FK_id(FK, int, null)
- locking_guid(uniqueidentifer, null)
- locked_time(datetime, null)
- external_guid_4(uniqueidentifier,
  null)
- corrected_time(datetime, null)
- is_add(bit, not null) score(int,
  null)
- row_version(timestamp, null)

*Indexes*

- PK_table(Clustered)
- IX_created_time(Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)
- IX_external_guid_1(Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)
- IX_guid(Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)
- IX_external_guid_3(Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)
- IX_state(Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually looks simply like indexing on a guid might be the culprit here:
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/can-guid-cluster-keys-cause-non-clustered-index-fragmentation/

Lately I've been finding a number of references that seem to support this.

Answer (score 3):

Note: SQL Server Best Practices state that indexes with less than 10,000 pages do not usually benefit from performance gains.

See     http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc966523.aspx
    http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.database.aspx?pr=blog

Here's a little snippet to identify when your DB needs defragging.In our product, we reduced this to 2000 and chose >20% fragmentation.
You can easily modify the script to tell you which indecies in particular.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS fragmented_indexes FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), null, null, null, null) as p WHERE p.avg_fragment_size_in_pages <= 1 AND p.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 20 AND p.page_count > 2000;
```

Comment: Paul Randall admits [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Where-do-the-Books-Online-index-fragmentation-thresholds-come-from.aspx) he pretty much made these figures up!

Comment: Wow, didn't know that. Thanks.But luckily, we ran our own tests to work out that 2000 was good for the general use of our product without alerting the user too soon (we make the product tell the user when they might be suffering performance problems based on this query).

Comment: I've edited the SQL since the original reply, as it didn't take into account the average page fragment size or the percentage fragmentation.

Comment: BTW the reports in the Management Data Warehouse give defragmentation suggestions I've never investigated whether these are based on the same thresholds or something different.

Comment: None of my indexes meet this criteria.  However, I think the cause for the high fragmentation, now that I am looking closer into the data that is covered by indexes, those with lower fragmentation rates have far more duplicate data in the columns (~3000 distinct values for 100,000 records versus ~99,000 distinct values per 100,000 records for the high fragmentation indexes).  So it looks like I am barking up the wrong tree as far as performance goes.  Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have enough data in the index to merit defragmenting. After you get a couple thousand rows in there, the rebuilds and reorgs will get rid of the fragmentation.

Until the index page count gets up to 100 or so, the fragmentation won't affect performance.

You'll also want to verify that your query is covered by the index and that the index is being used.

Run the query from the management studio (you can capture the query with sql profiler or the Activity Monitor if it is dynamic) and click "Include actual execution plan". This will tell you what index is being used and if the query is covered.

Comment: DB has 200,000+ rows at the moment, so the data volume above is covered.

Comment: And the index is being used in the execution plan.

Comment: So if you rebuild the index, does the fragmentation not go down?

Comment: No it does not, that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Turn db auto shrink off](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Auto-shrink-e28093-turn-it-OFF!.aspx). It seems to have a side effect of fragmenting indexes.

Comment: I hoped this was going to be an easy fix for this, but Auto Shrink is already off.